# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'items')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

I have other JSON data similar to this, hence, I would like to filter it.

```
const data = [{
      "1": {items: { Part1: true, Part2: true } },
      id: "zaMR9TR7hNV3p3VFNumyNbXMto93",
      displayName: name1
    }]
```

However, I keep getting the error of

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'items')

```
  const filter = data.filter(
    (a) =>
      a.["1"].items.Part1 == true
  );
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have an extra "." right before ["1"]

```
a["1"].items.Part1
```

By the way, if i were you, i would rename items by "item", because it's not an array, just an object.

Answer (score 2):

You are accessing elemet incorrectly. please use this

```
 const filter = data.filter(
    (a) =>
      a["1"].items.Part1 == true
  );
```

error was here, the extra dot(.) after a =>  a.["1"], it should be a["1"]